# 'str' object has no attribute '_encode_json'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I've been writing a test with RequestFactory to test one of my views, with the following code:

```
class ViewTestCase(TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUp(self):
    self.factory = RequestFactory
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        first_name='tester',
        username='test1', 
        password='123', 
        email='testuser@something.com'
        )

def test_room_creation(self):
    payload = {"titlePlanning": "Test1","styleCards": "Fibonnaci","deck": ["1","2","3"]}
    request = self.factory.post('/room', payload)
    request.user = self.user
    response = BeginRoom.as_view()(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

This is the data that I need to send to use POST:

```
class BeginRoom(APIView):
    permissions_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
    data= self.request.data
    user = request.user
    name = data['titlePlanning'].strip()
    styleCards = data['styleCards']
    cards = data['deck']
```

My problem is that whenever I run my tests I get the following error:

```
    data = self._encode_json({} if data is None else data, content_type)
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_encode_json'
```

What should I do? I'm lost from here and can't find anything related. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this inside `test_room_creation`:

```py
request = self.factory.post('/room', payload)
```

use this:

```py
request = self.factory.post('/room', payload, content_type='application/json')
```

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post):

> If you provide `content_type` as `application/json`, the data is serialized using `json.dumps()` if it’s a dict, list, or tuple.